# Disable / enable / configure network adapters in Windows system tray

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm looking for software, for Windows 7, that will allow me to do the following from the system tray (or from a global shortcut key):

- Enable or disable network adapters
- Set IPv4 properties for a given network adapter
- Ideally stores adapter enable/disable states and properties as profiles that I can switch between.
- Bonus: Select a wifi network for wifi adapters (although the existing network connection icon does this well).

Something similar to what [PowerPlan Assistant](http://www.powerplan7.com/features.htm) does for power profiles.

Does this software exist? I have been searching Google but can't find anything, but I'm not sure if perhaps there is a specialized application hidden in the depths of the internet somewhere. My search results are also polluted by topics regarding the standard Windows network connection tray icon.

The reason I'm looking for it is because depending on where I am and what I am doing I very frequently switch between the following network configurations:

- Wifi connection to router at home w/ DHCP
- Wifi connection to cell phone tethering (sometimes at home when the internet is down or for testing remote access)
- Wired connection to router at home w/ DHCP (wifi sometimes interferes when enabled)
- Wired connection to switch at work w/ static IP
- Wired connection to switches at various job sites w/ static IP and wifi must be disabled

I would like to avoid having to go through all the steps in the Network and Sharing Center each time; for some reason I spend a significant amount of time with that window open.

Paid software is OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use [netsh](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/PC/netsh.php) - it can be called from the command line or can be put into a set of batch files with appropriate names, you can then create desktop short-cuts for each of them.  In the batch files you can load a batch of commands and execute them within netsh.

Comment: That's a good idea; I can even put all the batch files in a new tool bar on the task bar for quick accessibility (and collapse it so it's just an arrow with a popup menu for a similar effect).